# Reading from file in c adds weird characters in the beginning

Tags: c, file

I have to read 2 letters from a file and then a text from the next line of the same file (the 2 letters are separated by a space). Now I need to replace the first letter with the second throughout the text.

This is my input:

```
a x
abecedar avion nuca
```

so the letter `a` will be replaced with `x`.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *in;
    in = fopen("in.txt", "r+");
    char litera1 = 0, litera2 = 0, s[100], aux[100] = "";

    fscanf(in, " %c", &litera1);
    fgetc(in);
    fscanf(in, " %c", &litera2);
    strcpy(aux, "");
    printf("%c %c\n", litera1, litera2);

    while (fscanf(in, "%s", aux) != EOF)
    {
        strcat(s, aux);
        strcat(s, " ");
    }
    s[strlen(s) - 1] = NULL;
    printf("%s\n", s);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        printf("%c\n", s[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == litera1)
            s[i] = litera2;
    }

    /*
    rewind(in);
    fprintf(in,"%s", s);    i have to overwrite in the same file
    fflush(in);
    fclose(in); */
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my output:

```
a x
@§@abecedar avion nuca
@
§
@
a
b
e
c
e
d
```

In another program I need to change capital letter into small and vice versa and the  swaps work just fine but I get this in front of the text:  `⌡`

How do I get rid of the first three characters? I displayed it letter by letter to check for the problem but I cannot figure it out. I suspect it's because of the moving to the new line, but I don't know how to fix it. Thank in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: `s[strlen(s)-1]=NULL;` should be `s[strlen(s)-1]='\0';`. `NULL` is used for pointers.

Comment: This `strcat(s,aux);` is a problem. The `s` has not been initialised. You intialiased `aux` but that was the wrong string.

Comment: Aside. Do you understand what the space does in `fscanf(in," %c", &litera2);`? You've  still kludged it with `fgetc(in);`

Comment: It's always so simple man... Thanks so much!

Comment: @Barmar isn't it completely useless, as `strlen` uses that null terminator to get the length?

Comment: i used fgetc(in) first time but i changed beacuse i tried to fix it thinking it's the problem=)

Comment: Another suggestion: `while(fscanf(in, "%s", aux) != EOF)` should be `while(fscanf(in, "%99s", aux) == 1)`. Two changes.

Comment: @BartFriederichs The null terminator is `'\0'`, not `NULL`.

Comment: What was `s[strlen(s)-1]=NULL;` supposed to do anyway? It shortens the string by 1, which might be relevant had you used `fgets()`, which retains the newline, but `fscanf` with `%s` does not.

Comment: Make sure you accept the best answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to initialize `s` otherwise `strcat(s, ...)` will be undefined behavior.  Either wiuth `char s[LEN+1] = ""` and then handle the return value from `fscanf()` differently, or like below to require input.
2. If the `while`-loop doesn't run `s[strlen(s)-1] = ...` will result in a buffer underflow.
3. Always check the return value of `fopen()` otherwise subsequent functions calls on the file handle will likely fail.
4. Always check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized data.
5. Always use a maximum field width when reading strings with `scanf()`.
6. Always check that you have sufficient space in the resulting array.  If the 2nd line of your input is less than 9 bytes your print statement will print uninitialized data.
7. It's good practice to `fclose()` when done.
8. Consider using `fgets()` or `getline()` to get a line instead of words.  You can subsequently patch up the line if consecutive or trailing space is an issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 100
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

int main(void) {
    FILE *in = fopen("in.txt", "r+");
    if(!in) goto err;

    char litera1;
    char litera2;
    if(fscanf(in, " %c %c", &litera1, &litera2) != 2) goto err;
    printf("%c %c\n", litera1, litera2);

    char s[LEN+1];
    char aux[LEN+1];
    if(fscanf(in, "%" str(LEN) "s", s) != 1) goto err;
    while(fscanf(in, "%" str(LEN) "s", aux) == 1) {
        if(LEN - strlen(s) < strlen(aux) + 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "full: s=\"%s\", aux=\"%s\"\n", s, aux);
            break;
        }
        strcat(s, " ");
        strcat(s, aux);
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
    size_t n = 9 < LEN ? 9 : LEN;
    for(size_t i=0; i<n && s[i]; i++)
        printf("%c\n", s[i]);

    fclose(in);
    return 0;
err:
    perror("");
    fclose(in);
    return 1;
}
```

and the output is:

```
a x
abecedar avion nuca
a
b
e
c
e
d
a
r
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from `s` being uninitialized, hence it may not contain an empty string at the beginning of the `for` loop and this random contents appears in the output.

You can simplify the code drastically by reading the file contents one byte at a time and substitute the letter if needed.

You specify in a comment that you *have to overwrite in the same file*: changing the file contents this way seems to be your task, but it is usually preferred to produce a new file with the modified contents, which is also much simpler and less error prone.

To modify the file in place, you can use `fseek()` to seek back to the place where to write the modified contents also to switch back from writing to reading. Note however that there are restrictions on seeking into text files on legacy platforms: to move the current position, you can only seek to a position previously returned by `ftell()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *in = fopen("in.txt", "r+");
    if (in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", "in.txt", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    int literal1 = fgetc(in);
    int space = fgetc(in);
    int literal2 = fgetc(in);
    int newline = fgetc(in);
    if (literal1 == EOF || space != ' ' || literal2 == EOF || newline != '\n') {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid format: need 2 characters separated by a space\n");
        fclose(in);
        return 1;
    }
    for (;;) {
        long pos = ftell(in);   
        int c = fgetc(in);
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        if (c == literal1) {
            // need to replace the letter:
            // seek back to the previous position
            fseek(in, pos, SEEK_SET);
            // overwrite the character with the replacement
            fputc(literal2, in);
            // seek to the current position to allow switching back
            //   to reading from `in`
            fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```